# Regex question: Match sequence only n times on a random place

Tags: regex, grep

I have a regex question, take for example:

1. ...AAA**BZBZB**CCCDDD...
2. ...**BZBZB**DDD**BZBZB**CCC...

I am looking for a regular expression that matches **BZBZB** just *n* times.
 in a line. So, if I wanted to match the sequence only once, I should only get the first line as output.
The string occurs on random places in the text. And the regex should be compatible with grep or egrep...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`grep '\(.*BZBZB\)\{5\}'` will do 5 times, but this will match anything which appears 5 times or more because grep checks if any substring of a line matches.  Because grep doesn't have any way to do negative matching of strings in its regular expressions (only characters), this cannot be done with a single command unless, for example, you knew that the characters used in the string to be matched were not used elsewhere.

However, you can do this in two grep commands:

`cat temp.txt | grep '\(.*BZBZB\)\{5\}' | grep -v '\(.*BZBZB\)\{6\}'`

will return lines in which BZBZB appears exactly 5 times.  (Basically, it's doing a positive check for 5 or more times and then a negative check for six or more times.)

Comment: Thanks, you helped me realised that I'd forgotten to escape the curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

From the grep man page:

> ```
>    -m NUM, --max-count=NUM
>     Stop  reading  a file after NUM matching lines.  If the input is
>     standard input from a regular file, and NUM matching  lines  are
>     output,  grep  ensures  that the standard input is positioned to
>     just after the last matching line before exiting, regardless  of
>     the  presence of trailing context lines.  This enables a calling
>     process to resume a search.  When grep stops after NUM  matching
>     lines,  it  outputs  any trailing context lines.  When the -c or
>     --count option is also  used,  grep  does  not  output  a  count
>     greater  than NUM.  When the -v or --invert-match option is also
>     used, grep stops after outputting NUM non-matching lines.
> ```

So we need two grep expressions:

```
grep -e "BZ" -o
grep -e "BZ" -m n
```

The first one finds all instances of "BZ" in the previous string, without including the content around the lines.  Each instance is spit out on its own line.  The second one takes each line spit out and continues until n lines have been found.

```
>>>"ABZABZABX" |grep -e "BZ" -o | grep -e "BZ" -m 1
BZ
```

Hopefully that is what you needed.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I didn't formulate the question correctly, what I mean was matching the sequence n times in a line.

Comment: n times per line for each line?

Answer (score 1):

Its ugly but if the grep can do look ahead assertions, this should work:

`/^(((?!BZBZB).)*BZBZB){5}((?!BZBZB).)*$/`

Edit - The {5} above is the n times variable in the OP.
       Looks like GNU grep does Perl like assertions using the -P option.

Perl sample

```
use strict;  
use warnings;  

my @strary = (  
  'this is BZBZB BZBZB BZBZB and 4 BZBZB then 5 BZBZB and done',  
  'BZBZBBZBZBBZBZBBZBZBBZBZBBZBZBBZBZBBZBZB BZBZB  BZBZB',  
  'BZBZBBZBZBBZBZBBZBZBBZBZB 1',  
  'BZBZBZBBZBZBBZBZBBZBZBBZBZBBZBZB 2',  
);  

my @result = grep /^(((?!BZBZB).)*BZBZB){5}((?!BZBZB).)*$/,  @strary;  

for (@result) {  
   print "Found: '$_'\n";  
}
```

Output

```
Found: 'this is BZBZB BZBZB BZBZB and 4 BZBZB then 5 BZBZB and done'
Found: 'BZBZBBZBZBBZBZBBZBZBBZBZB 1'
```

Comment: egrep has extended regular expressions, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't support look ahead assertions.  And if it does, that's not the right syntax.  It treats ! (or rather, \! since ! on the command lines is treated as an event reference even inside of single quotes) as the literal character "!".  So !? just matches "!" or "".

Comment: You need Perl style re's (> version 5 Perl). GNU grep would be `grep -P '^(((?!BZBZB).)*BZBZB){5}((?!BZBZB).)*$'` It would be a shame to run normal grep through a double iteration on the same file. This regex works correctly, I can post proof code in Perl if you need to see it.